# Change color of single character with javascript

Tags: javascript

Because I am not able to add HTML to a title tag I need to use Javascript to change the color of a single character. I am using the following code which works great but it only applies the change to the first one and not the following ones.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('h1');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('.', '<span style="color: red;">.</span>');
```

```html
<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>
```

I just can't find a solution to change the code so it will work on every single header.

Comment: Try [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: Do you care about the version of JS you're hitting? Have you looked at the documentation for [javascript forEach loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `querySelectorAll` and iterate over the `NodeList` you get from that using `for ... of`:

```js
const h1s = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
for (const h1 of h1s) {
  h1.innerHTML = h1.innerHTML.replace('.', '<span style="color: red;">.</span>');
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>
```

You can also use `forEach` (which is part of the `Array.prototype`, so you first need to cast your `NodeList` to an `Array`):

```js
const h1s = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
Array.from(h1s).forEach((h1) => {
  h1.innerHTML = h1.innerHTML.replace('.', '<span style="color: red;">.</span>');
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>
```

Last, but not least, you can use the good old indexed for-loop:

```js
const h1s = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
for (let i = 0; i < h1s.length; i++) {
  h1s[i].innerHTML = h1s[i].innerHTML.replace('.', '<span style="color: red;">.</span>');
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>

<h1>Hello.</h1>
```